# How does RDD.aggregate action work (i.e. how to understand the parameters)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can anybody give a detailed explanation of how below agrregate action in spark produces result of **(9,4)**

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,3))

rdd.aggregate((0, 0))
((x, y) =>
(x._1 + y, x._2 + 1),
(x, y) =>
(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))

res : (9,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **Spark 2.1.0** here (which should not matter much, but...)

Go to [the official documentation of `aggregate`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) (aka *scaladoc*) and read:

> Aggregate the elements of each partition, and then the results for all the partitions, using given combine functions and a neutral "zero value". This function can return a different result type, U, than the type of this RDD, T. Thus, we need one operation for merging a T into an U and one operation for merging two U's, as in scala.TraversableOnce. Both of these functions are allowed to modify and return their first argument instead of creating a new U to avoid memory allocation.

The signature is as follows (removed the implicit parameter as not particularly interesting):

```
aggregate[U](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, T) ⇒ U, combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U): U
```

The scaladoc says:

> **zeroValue** the initial value for the accumulated result of each partition for the seqOp operator, and also the initial value for the combine results from different partitions for the combOp operator - this will typically be the neutral element (e.g. Nil for list concatenation or 0 for summation)

In your case, `zeroValue` is `(0, 0)`.

> **seqOp** an operator used to accumulate results within a partition

In your case, `seqOp` is `(x, y) => (x._1 + y, x._2 + 1)` which is a function accepting two pairs, unfortunately named `x` and `y` (which I'd call `p1` and `p2` at the very least or even using pattern matching and partial function, i.e. `case ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) => ...`).

Given you've got `n` partitions (you can check it out using `rdd.getNumPartition`), `seqOp` is going to be called `n` times.

The scaladoc says:

> **combOp** an associative operator used to combine results from different partitions

which means that `combOp` will combine all the results of `seqOp` and apply the function:

```
(x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)
```

It's again badly written so you see too much and I'd even call *a noise*. I'd write the function as follows:

```
{ case ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) => (x1 + x2, y1 + y2) }
```

*Follow the types* and give proper names, and ultimately everything in Scala becomes much easier ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Basically the aggregate says: We want a tuple (a,b) where a is the sum of all elements and b is their count.

This is done by initializing to (0,0) and then we have two functions:

- The first function just does the summing when we get a single element at a time, i.e. the tuple is updated from a single element by adding the value to the first element and adding 1 (count) to the second.
- The second function merges two results so it just does element wise addition

Lets consider the example of your input data:

Lets say 1,2 is in partition 1 and 3,3 is in partition 3.

**Partition 1 calculation**

Partition 1 would start with (0,0).

Then the first function begins to work.

When we add the one we get (1,1). The first element is the sum (0 + y where y is 1) and the second is the count (0 + 1).

Now we add 2 so we get (1+2, 1+1)=(3,2). again the first element is the sum of values we saw so far and the second is their count.

**Partition 2 calculation**

On the second partition we again start with (0,0) and then we get (3,1) from the first 3 and (6,2) from the second.

**Merging the results**

Now the second function comes into play merging the two:
we merge (3,2) and (6,2) by summing both elements and getting (9,4)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it easy,

**Case 1: No partition**, just stand alone (*seqOp*). Focus on (x, y) =>
(x._1 + y, x._2 + 1), ignore partition.

```
{1,2,3,3}
            x._1    y      x._2     
(0+1,0+1)   0       1      0
(1+2,1+1)   1       2      1
(3+3,2+1)   3       3      2
(6+3,3+1)   6       3      3
Result:(9,4)
```

**Case 2: With partitions**, suppose 2 partitions (*combOp*)   {1,2}, {3,3} . Focus on 
(x, y) =>
(x._1 + y, x._2 + 1),

(x, y) =>
(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))

```
{1,2}
            x._1    y      x._2     
(0+1,0+1)   0       1      0
(1+2,1+1)   1       2      1
Result1: (3,2)

{3,3}
            x._1    y      x._2  
(0+3,0+1)   0       3      0
(3+3,1+1)   3       3      1
Result2: (6,2)

Final result:(9,4)
```